# UUID is unique for global? like swift, Android, and java

Tags: swift, unique, uuid

Actually I had a doubt reg. `UUID().uuidString` is **unique for globally like Android, iOS Swift, java and etc**.

UUID is like `9297EEEF-FE6D-4758-88BF-4051961B8619`

am generating unique id for each record in internal Database and for api callings. Same thing other teams(android and web) doing. Is that any possible for duplication?

Comment: You should read the [Wikipedia page on Version 4 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) - the type used by Swift's UUID class. Then read the [Collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) section under it. It ends with *"Thus, the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion."*. BTW - not my downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, So, planned to add some params like static text, and date, time with seconds.

```
String(format: "%@-IOS-%@", UUID().uuidString, Date().toString(format: "ddMMyyyyHHmmss"))
```

So, I think duplication percentage will reduce.

My result like:

> 9297EEEF-FE6D-4758-88BF-4051961B8619-IOS-17112022153206

Comment: While it does not hurt to append your own values to the UUID, it might not be necessary if you are looking to generate a unique string.

Comment: You are adding extra code and is obfuscating a well known identifier type with this and you have to do it on all platforms as well. Are you sure you are not creating more problems than you solve?

Answer (score 0):

`UUID().uuidString` generates a random UUID string - that is, a string with random digits and characters that fulfils the UUID v4 spec. This string is a completely random string and has nothing to do with the OS it is generated on. Here is [a website](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4) that generates random UUIDs.

*However*, due to its random nature, there is a tiny tiny chance that you'll get a duplicate UUID (whether on the same platform or another. This chance is so tiny, it's basically negligible.

Think of UUID v4 as being a very long random number that can be easily identified as a UUID at a glance.